# Next.js "Error occurred prerendering page " at build

Tags: next.js, build

my app working perfectly at development mode but when i tried to build i got this error.

```
  ▲ Next.js 14.1.3
   - Environments: .env

   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully
 ✓ Linting and checking validity of types
 ✓ Collecting page data
   Generating static pages (0/13)  [    ]TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
    at u (C:\Users\kuzey\Desktop\Desktop\ForMe\WEBFOLDERS\Projects\x\.next\server\chunks\923.js:1:10734)
    at i (C:\Users\kuzey\Desktop\Desktop\ForMe\WEBFOLDERS\Projects\x\.next\server\chunks\309.js:1:7174)
    at em (C:\Users\kuzey\Desktop\Desktop\ForMe\WEBFOLDERS\Projects\x\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:131226)
    at C:\Users\kuzey\Desktop\Desktop\ForMe\WEBFOLDERS\Projects\x\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:142926
    at Array.toJSON (C:\Users\kuzey\Desktop\Desktop\ForMe\WEBFOLDERS\Projects\x\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:146504)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at eR (C:\Users\kuzey\Desktop\Desktop\ForMe\WEBFOLDERS\Projects\x\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:134889)
    at eP (C:\Users\kuzey\Desktop\Desktop\ForMe\WEBFOLDERS\Projects\x\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:135332)
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:346:14)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\kuzey\Desktop\Desktop\ForMe\WEBFOLDERS\Projects\x\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:146956)

Error occurred prerendering page "/register". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
```

EDIT: I found what's wrong but still can't fix.

```
import { auth } from '@/lib/auth';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';

const AuthLayout = async ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  // const session = await auth();

  // if (session) {
  //   redirect('/home');
  // }
  return (
  // ...
  );
};

export default AuthLayout;
```

if i comment these lines everything works perfect.

EDIT 2: I just used `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'`  at the beginning of layout.tsx and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I think because this `auth()` function is expecting browser specific feature (like cookies or loacalStorage), it will not work as expected during the build time, because the code is executed in a Node.js environment. Not in the browser actually. Therefore we need to check a conditional check for client side only. Try following:

```js
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    // Execute client-specific code here
    const session = await auth();
    if (session) {
      redirect('/home');
    }
}
```